# flutter/pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/icons_helper-1.2.0-nullsafety.1/lib/icons_helper.dart:726:31: Error: Member not found: 'pie_chart_outlined'

Tags: flutter, runtime-error, pie-chart

In flutter showing this error I don't know why this comes, I updated all the plugins to lattest version

> /D:/flutter_sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/icons_helper-1.2.0-nullsafety.1/lib/icons_helper.dart:726:31:
> Error: Member not found: 'pie_chart_outlined'.   'pie_chart_outlined':
> Icons.pie_chart_outlined,

This is my pubspec.yaml file

```
 dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  dio: ^4.0.0
  retrofit: ^2.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2
  icons_helper: ^1.0.4
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  flutter_easyloading: ^2.0.0
  page_transition: ^1.1.6
  permission_handler: ^8.2.5
  geolocator: ^7.7.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.12
  multi_select_flutter: ^4.0.0
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0
  audioplayers: ^0.20.1
  flutter_switch: ^0.3.2
  file_picker: ^4.1.6
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  mime: ^1.0.1
  call_log: ^3.2.1
  firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  overlay_support: ^1.2.1
  system_alert_window: ^1.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.5
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0

flutter_native_splash:
  color : "fffff"
  image : assets/rsoft_logo.png
  android: true;
  ios: true;
  android12: true;

flutter_icons:
    android: "launcher_icon"
    ios: true
    image_path: "assets/launcher_icon.png"

flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

Comment: Just Try  `Universal Fix: (use both)`
`flutter clean`
`flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: Tried both commends still causing the err..

Comment: Maybe you can make the question's title cleaner by removing the content before the real error info, to help others to understand your question better

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to this path /D:/flutter_sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/icons_helper-1.2.0-nullsafety.1/lib/icons_helper.dart and find this file icons_helper.dart
2. Find Icons.pie_chart_outlined
   3)Replace “Icons.pie_chart_outlined” with “Icons.pie_chart_outline_outlined” then save the file.
   4)Run flutter pub upgrade (in android studio terminal)
   5)Then flutter run

I had this same error in material.dart, just follow the steps, I hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, Yah It works, But once I run flutter clean I need to every time

Comment: Is there any other way

Answer (score 1):

Go to this path `/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/icons_helper-1.2.0-nullsafety.1/lib/icons_helper.dart and find this file icons_helper.dart`

And find and remove the line `Icons.pie_chart_outlined` or replace with `Icons.pie_chart_outline_outlined`